# How can i Check my array have Value and more than Value in Swift4.2?

Tags: arrays, swift4.2, xcode10.1

i am facing one problem regrading array have already some values and it keep on updating ,now how can i check Array have more than that value or not ?

arrData = [NSNumber(value: categories.count), NSNumber(value: 6.9), NSNumber(value: 9.5), NSNumber(value: 14.5), NSNumber(value: 18.2), NSNumber(value: 21.5), NSNumber(value: 25.2), NSNumber(value: 26.5), NSNumber(value: 23.3), NSNumber(value: 18.3), NSNumber(value: 13.9), NSNumber(value: 9.6)]

suppose 9.5 value in array ,i want to check 9.5 value as well as more than that values(9.5) in My Array

Answer (score 0):

try below solution for getting value equal to 9.5 or more than that

```
let arrData = [NSNumber(value: 5.6), NSNumber(value: 6.9), NSNumber(value: 9.5), NSNumber(value: 14.5), NSNumber(value: 18.2), NSNumber(value: 21.5), NSNumber(value: 25.2), NSNumber(value: 26.5), NSNumber(value: 23.3), NSNumber(value: 18.3), NSNumber(value: 13.9), NSNumber(value: 9.6)]

      //For Filter Data 
       let arrValue = arrData.filter{ Double(truncating: $0) >= 9.5 }
       print(arrValue)
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '(NSNumber) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'NSPredicate', i am getting this error.

Comment: let arrValue = arrData.filter{ Double(truncating: $0) >= 9.5 } this line

Comment: The above example work without an error for me. Can you share your demo code? so I can check why you get this an error